# How can I transform data from tidy to a unique format?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset in which there are dates describing a time period of interest, as well as events ("Tests" in my toy example) that can fall inside or outside the period of the interest. The events also have a time and some dichotomous characteristics.

My collaborator has asked me to transform the data from this format:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3), StartDate = structure(c(315878400, 
315878400, 357696000, 323481600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), EndDate = structure(c(316137600, 316310400, 
357955200, 323654400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    TestDateTime = structure(c(316135500, 315797700, 357923700, 
    323422560), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    TestName = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test1", "Test3"), Characteristic = c("Fast", 
    "Slow", "Fast", "Slow")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Waah3.png)

to this format:

[desired state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9zit.png)

I am unsure how to accomplish this transformation or set of transformations using R, but I believe it is possible.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
    select(-c(StartDate,EndDate)) %>% # Remove extra columns
    tidyr::spread(TestDate, TestTime) %>% # Spread df to long form
    select(-Characteristic, everything()) %>% # Move Characteristic to the end of the df
    group_by(ID) %>% # Group by ID and
    group_split() # split it
```

Take on count that the date columns of the final `df` are not exact as the "desire" state.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Victor, thank you so much for helping to answer what I believe is my first question on this forum. I am closer to getting this figured out!